# How to convert int or decimal to string in MVC4

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC4, and im struggling with simple concept.

The problem is, I need to display code with name separated with - in dropdown list...

In controller(GET) i did like this

```
 update ( collection("Code").ToString )
```

In Html(View)

```
<tr><td>Customer Sub Group Name </td><td>@Html.DropDownList("CustomerSubGroupId")
</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Convert.ToString(number)

this is another way to convert to string

Comment: VB will actually let you leave off the parentheses.

Comment: @Zeeshan... its not working...if i put round brackets

Comment: @shubha Shetty i have modified the answer lets see if it works, if it is not working again, then problem is somewhere else in your code...